# Release SAS memory

Tags: memory, sas

I was running some code on SAS that was generating data and for some reason, it froze. I quit the program and relaunched SAS, but noticed it didn't clear the memory. It's a lot of data, about 20 gigs, so losing that much space is more than I'm willing to give up. Normally, when I close and relaunch SAS it clears that memory, but this time it didn't, even after restarting the desktop (it's a Windows PC on Windows 10). Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: You mean physical RAM or hard disk space?

Comment: Sorry, hard disk space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes runaway processes that do not end gracefully will leave their temporary data in your WORK directory. Here are two ways to do it:

**Use cleanwork.exe**

Run the following in an elevated command prompt, where C: is the drive SAS is installed and your SAS WORK directory resides.

```
"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\cleanwork.exe" /v C:
```

This will search your entire volume for temporary SAS files and it could take a while. If you want to *only* clean your WORK directory and make it run faster, you can find it in sas9.cfg file. For example:

```
"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\cleanwork.exe" /d "%TEMP%\SAS Temporary Files"
```

[Documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0j43jculk2kasn1qh5h12f3kl3z.htm)

**Delete it manually from WORK**

To get to your WORK directory:

1. Open SAS
2. Type the following code:

   `%put %sysfunc(getoption(work));`
3. Check your log. You'll see something like this:

   `C:\Path\_TD_<numbers and letters>\<id>`
4. Go to the directory that the `_TD` is in.

Delete all files/folders in this directory that start with:

- #TD
- _TD
- SAS_util

**NOTE**: If you are using Enterprise Guide, you can delete everything in the "EGTEMP" folder. If you're having issues deleting temporary files in it, [check out Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). It's a bit oldschool but still works on Windows 10! Great little tool.